# invoking java scriptlet in JSP using HTML

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I am trying to find a way to invoke a piece of `java code` within the JSP using HTML form

```
  <form method="get" action="invokeMe()">

       <input type="submit" value="click to submit" />

  </form>


  <%
     private void invokeMe(){
       out.println("He invoked me. I am happy!");   
     }
  %>
```

the above code is within the JSP. I want this run the scriptlet upon submit

I know the code looks very bad, but I just want to grasp the concept... and how to go about it.

thanks

Comment: sorry @kholofelo but you can not do so.you can do this using using Serlets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *Ajax* to submit form to **servlet** and evaluate java code, but stay on the same window.

```
<form method="get" action="invokeMe()" id="submit">

       <input type="submit" value="click to submit" />

</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").submit(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "your servlet here(for example: DeleteUser)",
                data : "id=" + id,
                success : function() {
                    alert("message");
                }
            });
            $('#submit').submit(); // if you want to submit form
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry,**not possible.**

Jsp lies on  `server` side and `html` plays on `client side` unless without making a `request` you cannot do this :)

Answer (score 3):

you cannot write a `java method` in `scriptlet`. Because at `compilation` time code in `scriptlet` becomes part of `service` method. Hence method within a method is wrong.

How ever you can write `java methods` within `init tag` and can call from `scriptlet` like below code.

```
<form method="get" action="">

       <input type="submit" value="click to submit" />

  </form>

    <%
        invokeMe();

     %>

  <%!
       private void invokeMe(){
       out.println("He invoked me. I am happy!");   
     }
   %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.
When the form is submitted, it sends a request to the server. You have 2 options:

Have the server perform the desired action when the it receives the request sent by the form

or

Use Javascript to perform the desired action on the client:

```
 <form name="frm1" action="submit" onsubmit="invokeMe()"
 ...
 </form>

 <script>
 function invokeMe()
 {
 alert("He invoked me. I am happy!")
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this since JSP rendering happens on server-side and client would never receive the Java code (ie. the `invokeMe()` function) in the returned HTML. It wouldn't know what to do with Java code at runtime, anyway!

What's more, `<form>` tag doesn't *invoke functions*, it sends an HTTP `form` to the URL specified in `action` attribute.