# how to migrate a particular code from ASP.NET to JAVA in eclipse IDE using tomcat server

Tags: java, html, asp.net-mvc, jsp

I have one index.cshtml file wherein it has code that references to some method of a class in other file and stored in windows.baseurl . Now I want to write the index.cshtml as index.html file. 
So basically I have 2 problems
1) What is windows.baseurl in ASP.NET in index.cshtml
2) if I want to migrate that index.cshtml file to index.html file, then how do i reference that baseurl() method in html file using JSP.

the code in index.cshtml file is

> window.baseurl = "@Html.GetBaseUrl()"

the code which I wrote in java, the method is

> protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
>       response) throws ServletException, IOException {
>                 NewMethod.getBaseUrl(request);      }

so how do i call the above method using JSP in index.html file

Comment: If your file is a jsp file, you could get the base url directly from the request object (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271075/how-to-get-the-base-url-from-jsp-request-object)

Comment: No.. I have made index.html file and using scriptlet tag i want to call that java method.

Comment: I dont think thats possible. jsp is executed on the server-side while scriplet tags contain code that is executed on the client side.

Comment: However you could to something like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032899/invoking-java-scriptlet-in-jsp-using-html), but that doesn`t seem to be very intuitive.